# iOS application approved on AppStore but reject on external Testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, appstore-approval

I uploaded my ios application on **AppStore** for review. my app was approved on AppStore and is pending developer release. after that, I uploaded the same build on external **test flight** but unfortunately, the build rejects by the beta apple-review team.

is there any possibility that apple stop me to release the application on AppStore?

Comment: can you please share rejection metadata provided by beta apple-review team.

Comment: yes, I can provide it, but unfortunately, I removed the build from the external test flight and now I am not able to select again that same build.

Comment: Require more detail on your rejection